# @nx/enforce-module-boundaries errors not being displayed inline inside VS Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc, nx-monorepo

I've created a new Nx workspace and setup some `@nx/enforce-module-boundaries` rules. When running the `nx lint` command manually I get the errors I expect when importing a module where I'm not supposed to.

```
nx run-many --all --target=lint

    √  nx run admin:lint  [existing outputs match the cache, left as is]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    √  nx run admin-customer-shell:lint  [existing outputs match the cache, left as is]
    √  nx run admin-e2e:lint  [existing outputs match the cache, left as is]                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

    ×  nx run admin-customer-feature-feature-list:lint
       Linting "admin-customer-feature-feature-list"...
 >  NX   Running target lint for 4 projects
D:\Projects\LittleSalon\little-salon\libs\admin\customer\feature\feature-list\src\lib\feature-list.module.ts
  3:1  error  A project tagged with "type:feature" can only depend on libs tagged with "type: feature", "type:data-access", "type: ui", "type: utils", "type: models"  @nx/enforce-module-boundaries

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)ature-feature-list:lint

Lint errors found in the listed files.che]
```

But in my IDE (Vs Code) I don't get the same error inline. So when working, it all seems fine. I ofcourse want immediate feedback whilst working on my app and not only in my CI/CD pipeline.

[image: Screenshot from file containing an error inside VS Code]
In this example I expect an error on line 3, because my boundary rules do not allow shells to be imported inside features.

I've made my repository public so you can see the source code: https://github.com/JREU/LittleSalon

I've deinstalled all extensions except for EsLint, Nx Console and prettier.
[image]

The EsLint output doesn't show me any errors:
[image]

Here's my settings.json file:

```
{
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "git.confirmSync": false    
}
```

Edit: As a test I've installed Rider, which does give me inline errors. So it seems to be a VS Code issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to resolve this issue myself by doing a clean install of VS Code. I'm on Windows, so I followed the following steps:

1. Uninstall Vs Code
2. Remove all cache and log level files by removing the `code` folder from the roaming folder `C:\Users\<your-pc-username>\AppData\Roaming\`.
3. Delete all vs code extensions by removing the `.vscode` folder from `C:\Users\<your-pc-username>\`
4. Restart

Source: https://shihab1511.medium.com/clean-uninstall-vs-code-windows-pc-to-start-afresh-facaec6f5bf2

As of now I still do not know which of my settings/extensions caused the issue.